# declaration of a list (or vector) of 2d arrays of sizes known at runtime

Tags: c++, list, templates, std, stdvector

I have many 2D arrays for which I will only know the size at runtime.

```
  int arr1[i][k];
  int arr2[i][k];
  ...
```

Actually they get created in a for loop. I need them all in memory at the end of the loop:

```
   list<????> mylist;
   mylist.push_back(arr1);
   mylist.push_back(arr2);
```

How can I push them into a std::vector or std::list ? All the examples I have seen require knowing the size of the array in advance.

Comment: Seeing as you have `int arr1[][]`, the type of arr1 is just an int**. Try putting that into the list template.

Comment: C++ does not yet support variable-length C-style arrays. If your array size is only known at runtime, consider using a vector.

Comment: @ZachStark: No, it's an array of arrays, not a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something copyable and assignable, such as an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can either write your own 2D class wrapping a single vector, which would be the preferred option, or use a vector of vectors. For example (untested):

```
class Array2D
{
 public:
  Array2D(int rows, int cols) : cols_(cols), data(rows*cols) {}
  int& operator()(int i, int j) { return data_[i*cols_ + j]; }
  const int& operator()(int i, int j) const { return data_[i*cols_ + j]; }
  // to-do: add an efficient, exception safe swap method.
 private:
  unsigned int cols_;
  std::vector<int> data_;
};

Array2D arr1(i, j);
Array2D arr2(i, j);
std::list<Array2D> mylist;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr1(i, std::vector<int>(k));
std::list<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> mylist;
```

Comment: @chickenpox I think this is quite straight-forward. Once you have a decent 2D array class, you can use it everywhere.

Comment: What about a 3D array, same thing as in your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For 2d array declaration you can use maps

```
std::maps<int,int> Array2D;
loop{
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    Array2D[a]=b;
}
```